# Keep terminal open when running Python GUI application from bash script

Tags: python, bash, terminal

This is probably a very simple question, but I just can't figure it out. I've coded a Python GUI application (uses PyQT), and all I want to do is to launch it with an executable script. I'm still debugging the application, so it'd be nice if the terminal stays open to see any errors/print statements/exceptions thrown.

This is what I've got in my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
x-terminal-emulator -e cd dirname && python GUIapp.py
```

It successfully runs the Python application, but once the application loads, the terminal automatically closes. The application continues to run after the terminal closes.

I know I can open a terminal and then simply type in "cd dirname && python GUIapp.py", but I'm lazy.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--hold` or `--noclose` option. They have the same function with different name.

So change script to

```
#!/bin/sh
x-terminal-emulator --noclose -e cd dirname && python GUIapp.py
```

If you are looking for a command option, always check `--help`. In this case it gives you the needed information.

```
user@host:~/projects$ x-terminal-emulator --help
Usage: x-terminal-emulator [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] [args] 

Terminal emulator

Generic options:
  [...]

Options:
  [...]
  --hold, --noclose         Do not close the initial session automatically when it ends.
  [...]
```